# Cursor position relative to items

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I can't seem to find the edit cursors current position in between items of the Selectize input box. I would've liked to get updates on the position as well. Is it non-existant functionality?

Comment: Can you post snippets of your code to better explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually it's no code to show for this yet. In Selectize I can have multiple items selected and can move the cursor in between them, but I can't seem to find a way to see which items the cursor is placed between (or before or after). I want to repopulate the list based on where the cursor is. 

selectize.items gives me an array with the already selected items. I expected to find something like selectize.cursorItemPosition to give the the current cursor position, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I can't find any API's, looking at the DOM it generates I think its definitely *possible* to get the cursor location. Maybe I will post a fiddle if I get some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a function that uses jQuery to locate the input in the selectize control's DOM.

```
function getCursorIndex (elementId) {
  var elementsInContainer = $(elementId).parent().find(".selectize-input").children();

  var idx = 0;
  $(elementsInContainer).each(function() {
    if(this.tagName == "DIV") {
      idx++;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  return idx;
}
```

Note that it gives you the location of cursor as zero if it is the first element in the input area visible on screen. Try out the fiddle below to understand how it works.

Also, given the fact that I am reading the DOM elements to get this value instead of using the API's, the example may break in future versions of selectize.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3n4oh257/2/

Comment: Neat way to select and remove selected items in a Selectize widget! I dig it.